# Check If Service Is Started With Espresso By Click On View

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-espresso, mockito-kotlin, android-unit-testing

I want to test that when i click on btnRestore , CloudRestoreService should be start.
how to test this ?

```
@Test
fun testBtnRestore_expectedIntentCloudRestoreService() {
    Intents.init()
    onView(withId(R.id.btnRestore))
        .check(matches(isDisplayed()))
        .check(matches(isEnabled()))
        .perform(click())
    intended(hasComponent(CloudRestoreService::class.java.name))
    Intents.release()
}
```